# Ubuntu 11.04 mouse error

Tags: 11.04, mouse

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 (Win7 Dual-boot) today, so I am a newbie in the world of Ubuntu. I like it, because it is very new and interesting to me, but there is a thing, that really annoys me. When I have a window open, it is usually okay to use the mouse, but if I open a new window (like firefox) then I can't use the mouse on the 2nd window.

I can't click on anything, but I can use the keyboard to navigate with the arrows, but it is really hard to me, because i can't use 2 windows at one time. Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: What does "cannot use the mouse on the second window" mean?

Comment: I mean if I open a new window then it my mouse still stays on my first window and I can't click on anything on the second window, or at the desktop.

Comment: But you can move the cursor? Can you use the global menus? Is the new window in the foreground or background?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information. What mouse is it ? What graphics card ?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I read about a similar problem recently, could it be that you have a Saitek Cyborg RAT mouse? If so, try this: [How to Fix Saitek Cyborg RAT Series Mice in Ubuntu • TechSpheria](http://techspheria.com/2011/02/how-to-fix-saitek-cyborg-rat-series-mice-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind for the next answers. But I don't think it is necessary to edit this answer because the question is closed anyway. Is that okay?

Comment: yeah it's okay.